# Prefix on references

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

When I label a definition, theorem..., and I later reference it, I don't get the "Definition" or "Theorem" prefix. I'm using `hyperref` on **Overleaf**.

In the following image, I want to make the hyperlink automatically say: "Definition 1.1", instead of just "1.1", and if possible, make “Definition” also be part of the link.

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\title{Math class}
\author{Pablo García López}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Line integral}

\begin{definition}[Opposite curve]
\label{curvaOpuesta}
Let $\gamma: [a, b] \to \R$ be a curve $\mathcal{C}^1$. Then the \textcolor{red}{opposite curve} is defined as $-\gamma: [-b, -a] \to \R, (-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t)$
\end{definition}

We can observe that on \ref{curvaOpuesta} we don't need \dots

\end{document}
```

Can I get any help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: You want to have a look at `cleveref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\autoref` instead of plain `\ref`. Moreover, since the `hyperref` package has not been told what kind of prefix label to use with `definition` objects, you'll also need to run the instruction

```
\def\definitionautorefname{definition}
```

Alternatively, you could load the `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink`, after loading `hyperref`, and then use `\cref` and `\Cref` to create cross-references that automatically include the object's name; the latter will typeset the first letter of the object's name in UPPERCASE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\def\definitionautorefname{definition}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % always load cleveref *after* hyperref

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Line integral}

\begin{definition}[Opposite curve] \label{curvaOpuesta}
\dots
\end{definition}

\ref{curvaOpuesta}

\autoref{curvaOpuesta}

\cref{curvaOpuesta}

\Cref{curvaOpuesta}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution uses `cleveref` (to be loaded after `hyperref`):

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

    \hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue}
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

    \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

    \title{Math class}
    \author{Pablo García López}
    \date{June 2022}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Line integral}

    \begin{definition}[Opposite curve]
    \label{curvaOpuesta}
    Let $\gamma: [a, b] \to \R$ be a curve $\mathcal{C}^1$. Then the \textcolor{red}{opposite curve} is defined as $-\gamma: [-b, -a] \to \R, (-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t)$
    \end{definition}

    We can observe that on \cref{curvaOpuesta} we don't need \dots

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP mentioned wanting to "make “Definition” also be part of the [hyper]link".

Comment: @Mico: I hadn't noticed this requirement. 'Twas easily fixed, as it was just a matter of loading time option. Thanks for the warning!